# Different Default Sort_by for Search & Category Listing

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

We can set a `<default_sort_by>` which might be something like "Best Seller" but with Search results, I would rather the `Default_sort` be `Relevance`.

First of all, is it possible to setting options like this though Magento's current configuration?

If Not, where would we look at implementing logic that would check to see if `relevance` (in this case) is available.. IF so, make `relevance` the default sort. ELSE use `bestseller`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set default sort by 'relevance' in search, one of the way to set hidden field like this in your search form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="order" value="relevance">
<input type="hidden" name="dir" value="desc">
```

By doing this your search will be ordered by relevence,descending while you can keep default product listing to whatever you want.